# Unable to use bracket notation to access object's properties if index is a variable

Tags: typescript

How do I convert the Javascript below into TypeScript?

```
function getProperties(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find a workable solution. Object keys in TypeScript apparently are not of type `string` but are of `string literal type`. Is it possible to iterate through the properties of an object whose exact type is not known at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you could define `obj` to be `Record<string, any>` or `{ [key: string]: any }` (that's the same thing, the first one is just fancier and shorter). Now typescript will consider that object's keys are `string` type and let you index object with any string (that's not always desirable, but for this function it's fine)

```
// function getProperties (obj: { [key: string]: any }) 
//       or
function getProperties(obj: Record<string, any>) {
  for(let key in obj) {
    // too lazy to write hasOwnProperty stuff
    console.log(obj[key])
  }
}
```

Also you could use `Object.keys` instead of the loop, because it returns an array of just strings (just `string`s from the typescript's perspective)

```
function getProperties(obj: object) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => console.log(x))
}
```

Typescript also has `keyof` operator that lets you find out the type of the keys of an object, but it is mostly useful when your object is not just a random one, but has specific properties, given by an interface or a class or something like that